# Need Help Merging two Rewrite Rules using mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to smush together two rewrite conditions into one that I found searching the net. The problem is if one works the other won't:

```
### [RULE1: remove the .php at end of file / url] 
# If requested URL-path plus ".php" exists as a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
# Rewrite to append ".php" to extensionless URL-path
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

And

```
### [RULE2: http to https redirection]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Apparently whichever rule is placed at top works.

So I need a way to remove the php extension at the end of url however if the url contains http instead of https, it should also automatically redirect to https version of script.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are setting every page to be accessed via https. There are some mistakes which I have corrected below. Do this:

```
#rule to make both WORK
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
### [RULE1: remove the .php at end of file / url] 
# If requested URL-path plus ".php" exists as a file
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
# Rewrite to append ".php" to extensionless URL-path
 RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]

### [RULE2: http to https redirection]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#The next line is not required.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @user1212150 Welcome. Do accept the answer so that Q/A will be closed.